# use local config to auto switch to root after ssh login

Tags: linux, debian, ssh

Sometimes I have to login to mutiple servers and switch to root.
for now my ssh config looks like this

```
  Host *
    User xxx
    Port 32200

  Host hostnamexxx
    HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Can I change local (ssh) config only to login in the server and automaticlly switch to root using password?
It seems like a less secure way to store the password in a unencypted file though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that `expect` can handle this from this [issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288259/script-ssh-login-to-server-and-pass-root-password) and other sources.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set HOSTNAME [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ssh -t $HOSTNAME su -
# expect "密码:"
log_user 0
send "xxxxx\r"
interact
```

Set an alias for this script if you like.

```
alias sshr="/root/expect_ssh.sh"
```

This scrpt works fine with my ssh config, but may need some change according to yours in the `spawn ssh` command.

Unforunately I know little about expect script and the script above has something that might need improvement.

1. `expect "密码:"` is not working, I changed it to `Password:`, `Password:` . Didn't work.
2. I tried using `log_user 0` to supress the output of send, to hide the password of course.Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than "switching" to root after login, you can login as root in `ssh`.

You can add to your config file the `User root` line:

```
  Host hostnamexxx
    HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    User root
    IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This means that when you try to `ssh` to hostnamexxx, it will try to login directly as root. This is equivalent to running the following `ssh` command:

```
$ ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -l root hostnamexxx
```

However, it will not be able to use the `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` file, since it's protected and only readable by root, and it will ask for `root`'s password on the destination host.

```
$ ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -l root hostnamexxx
Warning: Identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa not accessible: Permission denied.
Password:
```

Once you enter `root`'s password, you'll be logged to the destination as root.

If you don't want to provide a password, you can copy `root`'s Identity file from `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` (assuming you have `sudo` permissions for `root`, of course) to your home folder and change the owner to your user:

```
$ sudo cp /root/.ssh/id_rsa $HOME/.ssh/root_id_rsa && sudo chown <your username> $HOME/.ssh/root_id_rsa
```

And then use `$HOME/.ssh/root_id_rsa` as the `IdentityFile`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. But those servers I am working with are not allowed to be logged in as root. Is there any workaround? Quite strange this process hasn't been automated.